# Socket.Accept fail to exit

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have a `socket.Accept()` which blocks the code on thread X.
When exiting the program I run `socket.Close()` and socket.Dispose() on UI thread 
(double checked that it is the same instance...),
but thread X still stack on the `socket.Accept()` and refuses to exit.

I turned thread X to background thread and Aborted it brutally,
but I don't like this solution.
Does anyone knows what causing it?
or what else can I do?
ittay

Comment: not sure if it's possible. Marking thread as background thread should be enough as well. Otherwise, could you use Socket.BeginAccept instead?

Comment: Your error is certainly away. Whenever you call `Dispose()` on your listener `socket.Accept()` will always raise `ObjectDisposedException`. Could you show us more of your Thread X code ?